# Why lock-based programs do not compose correct thread-safe fragments?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, mutex

Tim Harris said:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory#Composable_operations

> Perhaps the most fundamental objection [...] is that lock-based
>   programs do not compose: correct fragments may fail when combined. For
>   example, consider a hash table with thread-safe insert and delete
>   operations. Now suppose that we want to delete one item A from table
>   t1, and insert it into table t2; but the intermediate state (in which
>   neither table contains the item) must not be visible to other threads.
>   Unless the implementor of the hash table anticipates this need, there
>   is simply no way to satisfy this requirement. [...] In short,
>   operations that are individually correct (insert, delete) cannot be
>   composed into larger correct operations. —Tim Harris et al.,
>   "Composable Memory Transactions", Section 2: Background, pg.2[6]

What does it mean?

If I have 2 hash maps `std::unordered_map` and 2 mutexes `std::mutex` (one for each hash map) then I can simply lock its both: http://ideone.com/6RSNyN

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map1 ( {{"apple","red"},{"lemon","yellow"}} );
std::mutex mtx1;

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map2 ( {{"orange","orange"},{"strawberry","red"}} );
std::mutex mtx2;

void func() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock1(mtx1);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock2(mtx2);

    std::cout << "map1: ";
    for (auto& x: map1) std::cout << " " << x.first << " => " << x.second << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl << "map2: ";
    for (auto& x: map2) std::cout << " " << x.first << " => " << x.second << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    auto it1 = map1.find("apple");
    if(it1 != map1.end()) {
        auto val = *it1;
        map1.erase(it1);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(1000));
        map2[val.first] = val.second;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::thread t1(func);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(500));
    std::thread t2(func);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

If I want to implement myself thread-safe hash map `my_unordered_map` then I will implement such thing:

```
template<typename key, template val>
class my_unordered_map {
    std::recursive_mutex mtx_ptr;
    void lock() { mtx_ptr->lock(); }
    void unlock() { mtx_ptr->unlock(); }
    template<typename mutex_type> friend class std::lock_guard;
public:
 // .. all required public methods which lock recursive mutex before do anything
    void insert(key k, val v) { std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mtx); /* do insert ... */ }
    // ...
};
```

And will use it such:

```
my_unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map1 ( {{"apple","red"},{"lemon","yellow"}} );

my_unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map2 ( {{"orange","orange"},{"strawberry","red"}} );

void func() {
    std::lock_guard<my_unordered_map> lock1(map1);
    std::lock_guard<my_unordered_map> lock2(map2);

    // work with map1 and map2
    // recursive_mutex allow multiple locks in: lock1(map1) and map1->at(key)
}
```

Similar I get thread-safe code and fully sequential consistency for both map1 and map2.

But did about which cases this is said?

> Perhaps the most fundamental objection [...] is that lock-based
>   programs do not compose: correct fragments may fail when combined.

Comment: Presumably the intention is for the operation to fail transactionally: You extract key k from map1 only if map2 doesn't already contain key k. You cannot do that with just one private mutex per map, since the transaction needs to lock both mutexes together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is perfectly fine on its own.

Another program, for a different task in another thread, might use instead something like

```
void func_other() {
    std::lock_guard<my_unordered_map> lock2(map2);
    std::lock_guard<my_unordered_map> lock1(map1);

    // work with map1 and map2
}
```

Again, this is fine, on its own.

However, if we run both programs concurrently, there's a possible deadlock. Thread 1 locks map 1, thread 2 locks map 2, and now the next locks in both threads will wait forever.

Hence we can not compose the two programs naively.

Using STM instead of locks would always allow such kinds of composition (at some performance price).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, **lock-based** containers potentially may have deadlocks if changed the order of locks, i.e. "may fail when combined" means that we can rewrite this combined code to avoid any fails. But two **lock-free** containers generally can not make the consistency of two tables both. I.e. only STM can guarantee the absence of fails for the consistency of two tables. But instead deadlock the STM like any transaction-system may generate fails of transaction commit as transaction-rollback (on internals deadlocks or update conflicts) which we can process in software, isn't it?

Comment: @Alex Yes. In most STM approaches, even if there's some conflict, one transaction gets committed, and others may rollback instead. The STM engine can then retry the rolled-back transactions.

Comment: I.e. I have 2 ways: **1.** I should use STM with controlled transactions loop until their complete execution. **2.** Or I should solve deadlocks in lock-based programs myself, for example, by using `mutex.try_lock()` in loop for each of many required mutexes, also may be with `std::this_thread::yield()` after every certain number of repetitions, and if `mutex.try_lock() == false` after certain time (1 usec or 1 msec, ...) then throw an exception `throw my_roll_back_transaction();`, then catch it, rollback all made changes and retry loop again to change some tables together.

Answer (score 4):

The thread safe atomic operations of insert and erase typically hide the mutex within them.  This prevents access without locking.

In your case, you instead expose the mutexes.  This requires *every user* to properly wrangle the mutexes or it breaks.

With full access to the mutexes, you can rule out seeing the intermediary state safely: your code fails, because it does not use `std::lock` to guarantee mutex locking order is globally consistent, which can lead to deadlock if other code uses a different locking order.

This kind of problem -- where you have to be constantly aware of what mutexes will be needed for your transaction, and which you hold -- does not break down into small, easy to determine correct pieces.  Correctness becomes non-local, and then complexity explodes and bugs abound.

Comment: Yes, I hide `std::recursive_mutex mtx_ptr;` as private member which can be used directly only by `std::lock_guard` as friend. And I lock this mutex with RAII `std::lock_guard` in any methods such as: `insert()`, `erase()`, `find()`. Also I suggest to lock container manually by using `std::lock_guard` for many operations in one lock: find-erase-insert, two-tables consistency, ... And I see only one potentially problem of lock-based programs: deadlock on different orders of locks.